# Importing Mysql CSV to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to migrate CSV files that i generate from MySQL to AWS Redshift(PostgreSql). The query that generates CSV Files from Mysql is:

```
select * INTO OUTFILE 'filename' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```

and that is generating the output in the form of:

```
1559744 WIFI    123.63.13.93    conversation_list   page_load   0.16    success {"NetworkClass":"WIFI"} android_app     2016-06-15 00:00:00 c700b6e04077489 3.1_wo___ct_cd__gmmt_cst__  4.4.2
```

But while loading into Redshift I face the following error:

> Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x57 found at location 7`.

The query that I am using to load the CSV file is:

```
copy table_name FROM 's3://mybucket'    
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXX' 
delimiter AS '\t'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the AS after the delimiter

```
copy table_name FROM 's3://mybucket'    
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXX' CSV
delimiter '\t' MAXERROR 100000 IGNOREBLANKLINES FILLRECORD
```

or this

```
copy table_name FROM 's3://mybucket'    
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXX' delimiter ',' removequotes MAXERROR 100000 IGNOREBLANKLINES FILLRECORD
```

Comment: since you copy CSV file you should change the delimiter

Answer (score -1):

Check if the encoding of the csv file and your database match .Otherwise create the database again with the required encoding .

Comment: I cannot create the files with the encoding again , these are log files , of TB's in size.

Comment: don't change the file , drop the database , create a new database with proper encoding

Comment: I didn't get you , can you please share some external references to do so ?

Comment: Open the csv file , check the properties , somewhere you'll find the encoding ,now use this command to create the database .            CREATE DATABASE "db_name"
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1; Here i'm assuming the encoding is "UTF-8" ,